# Reshape Keras Input for LSTM

Tags: python, numpy, keras, lstm

I have two ndarrays, inputs and results, both consisting of multiple arrays looking like this:

```
inputs = [
  [[1,2],[2,2],[3,2]],
  [[2,1],[1,2],[2,3]],
  [[2,2],[1,1],[3,3]],
  ...
]
results = [
  [3,4,5],
  [3,3,5],
  [4,2,6],
  ...
]
```

I managed to split them up into train and test arrays, where train contains 66% of the arrays and test the other 33%. Now I'd like to reshape them for further use in my LSTM but my script fails when inputting them into np.reshape() function.

```
split = int(round(0.66 * results.shape[0]))
train_results = results[:split, :]
train_inputs = inputs[:split, :]
test_results = results[split:, :]
test_inputs = inputs[split:, :]
X_train = np.reshape(train_inputs, (train_inputs.shape[0], train_inputs.shape[1], 1))
X_test = np.reshape(test_inputs, (test_inputs.shape[0], test_inputs.shape[1], 1))
```

Please tell me how to use np.reshape() correctly in this case.

Basically I am loosely following this tutorial: https://github.com/Vict0rSch/deep_learning/tree/master/keras/recurrent

Comment: It depends on your input data, can you describe this row of the input? `[[1,2],[2,2],[3,2]]`

Comment: Thanks for answering. These arrays are time steps with two features each. However, these timesteps are just parts of one of many sequences.
So e.g. at day 1 hour 1 you have 1 apple and 2 oranges. Day 1 hr 2 you have 2 apples and 2 oranges... Day 2 hr 1 you have 2 apples and 2 oranges and so on..

Comment: It looks like you don't need to reshape

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just pass a tuple to `np.reshape`.

For an LSTM layer, you need the shape like `(NumberOfExamples, TimeSteps, FeaturesPerStep)`.

So, we need to know how many steps your sequence has. By the looks of your X array, I'll suppose you have 3 steps and 2 features.

If that's the case:

```
X_train = train_inputs.reshape((split,3,2))
X_test = X_test.reshape((test_inputs.shape[0], 3, 2))
```

If, otherwise, you want 6 steps of one feature, the shape is `(split,6,1)`. You can do anything, as long as the multiplication of the three elements in the shape must remain always the same

For the results. Do you want the results to be a result in sequence, matching the input steps? Or are they just single outputs (two independent outputs for the entire sequence)?

Since you've got 3 results, and I have assumed you have 3 time steps, I'll assume these 3 results are in sequence as well, so, I'll reshape them as:

```
Y_train = train_results.reshape((split,3,1)) #three steps, one result per step
#for this to work, your last LSTM layer should use `return_sequences=True`.
```

But if they are 3 independent results:

```
 Y_train = train_results.reshape((split,3)) 
 #for this to work, you must have 3 cells in the last layer, be it a Dense or an LSTM. But this LSTM must have `return_sequences=False`.
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you so much for helping. Your assumptions where correct, the results are in sequence as well as every result corresponds to a sequence. Now Numpy accepts my input. To use my input now with Keras I am doing `model.add(LSTM(3,input_dim=(3, 2),return_sequences=True))` but am getting error 'can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple'. Would you please be so kind to help?

Comment: You must use `input_shape` instead of `input_dim`. --- `input_shape` takes "tuples", while `input_dim` takes integers. (`input_dim` only makes sense in layers that don't need 2 dimensional input shapes)